# prevent xcode and interface builder from resizing preview images

Tags: xcode

For some reason when I add an image to xcode, the preview that xcode shows is smaller than the original image. The image also shows up smaller (about half size) in Interface Builder, but when I run the application everything is fine.

Is there a way to prevent xcode and Interface Builder from resizing image previews?

Answer (score 0):

The DPI setting of the images were not 72 dpi, that's what made xcode and interface builder resize the previews.

To avoid / fix it, set the images to 72 dpi.